# How to catch session from other page into TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

On my home page i catch some values/values/options into a session so i could use it into another page.
If i try to read back my session there is no problem, but if i try to use this in tcpdf then nothing appears.

for example is i use this on my home page if i submit the button to show the TCPDF page.:

```
session_start(); 
 if(isset($_POST['BevestigDienst']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION["DatumTijdDienst"] = $_POST['DatumTijdDienst'];
                        $_SESSION["DienstGebruiker"] = $_POST['DienstGebruiker'];
                        $_SESSION["SDienst"] = $_POST['SDienst'];
                        $_SESSION["SSVGebruiker"] = $_POST['SSVGebruiker'];
```

and this on antoher page call it back with this.:

```
session_start();
$Dienst = $_SESSION["SDienst"];
$tbl_style = '<style type="text/css">.tg .tg-cey7{font-size:8px;background-color:#FF5400;color:#ffffff;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}</style>';

$tbl_header = '<?php $_SESSION["Dienst"]; ?><table class="tg">';
$tbl_columns = '<tr>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="50" height="10" >Operator.: </th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="100" height="20" >Pascal Schuffelers</th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="40" height="20" >Datum.: </th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="80" height="20" >02-04-2019</th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="40" height="20" >Dienst.: </th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="20" height="20" > echo $Dienst </th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="80" height="20" >SSV.:</th>
                <th class="tg-cey7" width="120" height="20">echo $Persoon </th>
            </tr>';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_style . $tbl_header . $tbl_columns . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```

But if i try this on my tcpdf page , for example in this line.:

```
$tbl_columns = '<tr><th class="tg-cey7" width="50" height="10" >Operator.: </th><th class="tg-cey7" width="100" height="20" >Pascal Schuffelers</th><th class="tg-cey7" width="40" height="20" >Datum.: </th><th class="tg-cey7" width="80" height="20" >02-04-2019</th><th class="tg-cey7" width="40" height="20" >Dienst.: </th><th class="tg-cey7" width="20" height="20" ><?php echo $Dienst ?></th><th class="tg-cey7" width="80" height="20" >SSV.:</th><th class="tg-cey7" width="120" height="20"><?php echo $Persoon; ?></th></tr>';
```

i see everything but not the $Dienst.:

```
<th class="tg-cey7" width="20" height="20" ><?php echo $Dienst ?>
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: Did you start the session and assign a value to $Dienst _inside_ your “tcpdf page”? Doing it in a completely different script would of course not do the trick here …

Comment: No the session and value to $Dienst comes from the main page and not inside de my TCPDF page. But also a simple echo i don't see.

Comment: Well unless your main page _includes_ this pdf creating script, this is not how this works … You need to pick up the session again in every independent script. And variables that aren’t session variables are of course not available across different script instances at all - so assigning a value to $Dienst in one script, and then expecting that variable to be available in a totally independent script, that has nothing to do with the first one, is wrong to begin with.

Comment: But why don't i also don't see a simple text, for example a simple echo "test" i don't see. Also a pickup again the session sutch a menstioned in my first post, so at some point its going wrong.

Comment: Don’t expect anyone to be able to answer that based on the one-or-two-line code snippets you have shown so far. Provide a proper [mcve] that shows what you are actually doing in a comprehensible way please.

Comment: I edit my post with more codes, hopefuly is that enouth. The  $_SESSION["SDienst"]; has a value at that moment but in tcpdf i don't get it. In a normal pdf page i do get a value.

Comment: This still doesn’t show whether you actually picked up the session and assigned a value to a variable called `$Dienst` inside your “tcpdf page”, or not.

Comment: It's called in my example, the problem what i had is to read out off my example. I solved my problem just 10 minuts ago, it was after all a simple issue, what i did'nt see stopid. i tryed with echo and stuff but it is in TCPDF already in php so i only needed to put it like this.:  <th class="tg-cey7" width="20"  height="20" >' . $SDienst . '</th>   nothing more.